# Sequence of data from SQLite changed while displaying data in RecyclerView

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I have stored data in `SQLite` database. I need to display that data from database in `RecyclerView`.But first time when Data is retrieved and displayed in RecyclerView it is retrieved in Sequence as stored in database and set on Recyclerview.When I am trying to get the same data from Database and set on RecyclerView its changing the sequence automatically.
This is code to retrieve the data from `SQLite` database

```
public ArrayList<ReservationEntry> getDbReservation(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String query="SELECT * FROM "+ RESERVATIONS;
        Cursor c=db.rawQuery(query,null,null);
        ArrayList<ReservationEntry> reserveList=new ArrayList<>();
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do{
                ReservationEntry entry=new ReservationEntry();
                entry.setName(c.getString(0));
                entry.setNoOfPeople(c.getString(1));
                entry.setTime(c.getString(2));
                entry.setDate(c.getString(3));
                entry.setBirthday(c.getString(4));
                entry.setAniversary(c.getString(5));
                reserveList.add(entry);
            }while (c.moveToNext());
        }
        return reserveList;

    }
```

This is the code to set `RecyclerViewAdapter`

```
private void readDatabaseReservation(final ArrayList<ReservationEntry> dbList) {
        adapter=newReservationAdapter(dbList,getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

How to resolve this ?

Comment: Might be data is being updated. You can add order by clause in sql query. It will not change order unless new data is added or order by column is updated

Comment: did your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

You must add your adapter this function to change data and call notifyDataSetChanged.

So add this to your adapter

```
public void setData(ArrayList<ReservationEntry> dbList){
  this.yourListData = dbList;
  notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And use it like this

```
private void readDatabaseReservation(final ArrayList<ReservationEntry> dbList) {
    adapter.setData(dbList);
}
```

Hope it's help . for more add your adapter code